# Wireframe shader with barycentric coordinates shows black triangles

Tags: glsl, shader, wireframe

I created a mesh viewer using OpenGL and now I'm trying to realize a wireframe shader with barycentric coordinates following the guide found [here](http://codeflow.org/entries/2012/aug/02/easy-wireframe-display-with-barycentric-coordinates/).

The problem is that my mesh has lots of black triangles and I don't understand where is the error. Could it be in my barycentric vector?

My final rendering looks like this:

[image: BoneWrongWireframe]

In the code I created the barycentric vector in this way:

```
MatrixXi barycentric(3, faceCount*3);
for(int i=0; i<faceCount*3; i+=9){
    barycentric.col(i) << 1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1;
}
```

This is my vertex shader:

```
#version 330

in vec3 vertices;
in vec3 barycentric;

uniform mat4 proj;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;

out vec4 frag_color;
varying vec3 vBC;
void main(void) {
    mat4 mvp = proj * view * model;

    frag_color = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    vBC = barycentric;
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(vertices, 1.0);
}
```

And my fragment shader:

```
#version 330

varying vec3 vBC;
in vec4 frag_color;

out vec4 color;
float edgeFactor(){
        vec3 d = fwidth(vBC);
        vec3 a3 = smoothstep(vec3(0.0), d*1.5, vBC);
        return min(min(a3.x, a3.y), a3.z);
}

void main(void) {
        if(gl_FrontFacing){
            gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, (1.0-edgeFactor())*0.95);
        }
        else{
            gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, (1.0-edgeFactor())*0.7);
        }
}
```

Comment: It seems for some of your triangle have same `barycentric` value for all three its vertices. That probably means that you use indexed mesh. You should reorder your geometry somehow. BTW, why you don't just use `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE)`?

Comment: @KirillDmitrenko thank you for the answer. I think you could be right...how can I resolve it? I'm not sure how to create the vector. By the way I'm not using glPolygonMode() because I'm using nanogui and that function acts on the GUI as well. Also I'd like to choose between a transparent wireframe and a filled wireframe

Comment: I've posted some thoughts as an anwser

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as I've mentioned in the comments under the question, is that some of triangles of your mesh have the same `barycentric` attribute. Since, as far as I understand, you're using indexed mesh, reordering your data to resolve this issue may be tricky and depends greatly on topology of your model. However there's a bulletproof way to do that, it's just somewhat suboptimal: just get rid of indices (the code is C++-ish, but may need some reworking):

```
// Here're buffers with vertices and indices of the mesh.
std::vector<Vertex> vertexBuffer;
std::vector<int> indexBuffer;

std::vector<VertexWithBarycentricCoord> outputVertexBuffer;

const std::array<BarycentricCoord> COORDS({{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}});

for (int i : indexBuffer) {
    outputVertexBuffer.push_back({vertexBuffer, COORDS[i % 3]});
}
```

About `glPolygonMode`. You've pointed out in the comments that it may break GUI. But it doesn't have to: you can switch mode to `GL_LINE` only for your drawing and then switch it back to `GL_FILL`:

```
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINES);
// draw your mesh
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
// draw GUI
```

Also you've mentioned that you may want to "mix" wireframe of the mesh with filled mesh, and that may go in the way of using `glPolygonMode`, but it shouldn't. You can just draw the mesh twice:

```
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
// draw your filled mesh
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL) // to make sure that not all wireframe's fragments are culled in depth test.
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINES);
// draw your mesh again
```